# Struct and expected expression in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

The problem is this:

```
error: expected expression before 'Cadastro'
```

The code is not accepting the "Cadastro", it is asking for an expression before. This error is in several lines of code, especially in functions. The errors are between line 96 to 180. On line 149 there is an error of "expected indetifier or '(' before '[' token".

My code is having a problem with Struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define SIZE 100 //constante SIZE com valor de 3
#define MAXIMO 50
#define MAXS 11

typedef struct {
    int cod;
    int vazio;
    char nome_paciente[MAXIMO];
    int cpf_paciente[MAXS];
    int numero_carteirinha[MAXS];
    char nome_medico[MAXIMO];
    char especialidade_medico[MAXIMO];
    char data_consulta[MAXS];
    char data_revisao[MAXS];
    int codigo_medicamento[MAXS];
    int codigo_fornecedor[MAXS];
    float valor_medicamento[MAXS];
} Cadastro;

int opcao = 0, opt;

int verifica_pos(void);
int verifica_cod( int cod );
void cadastroP(int cod,int pos);
void listarDados();
void cadastroPedido();
void pesquisar(void);
void excluirCliente (void);

int main() //inicio do int main
{
    Cadastro cadastro[SIZE];

    do //do com while para realizar o codigo enquanto estiver dentro dos parametros
    {
        if(opcao==0) //if para a exibicao do menu
        {
            printf("\n1 - cadastro");
            printf("\n2 - pesquisa");
            printf("\n3 - listar");
            printf("\n4 - alterar");
            printf("\n5 - dados");
            printf("\n6 - sair\n"); //menu com as opcoes

            printf("\nEscolha sua opcao:\n");
            fflush(stdin); //limpando buffer
            scanf("%d", &opcao); //pegando a escolha do usuario
        }

        if(opcao==1) //if para entrar na area de cadastro
        {
            cadastrar();
        }

        if(opcao==2)
        {
            pesquisar();
        }

        if(opcao==3)
        {
            listarDados();
        }

        if(opcao==4)
        {
        }

        if(opcao==5)
        {
        }

        if(opcao==6)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if(opcao<0 && opcao>6)
        {
            printf("\nOpcao inexistente\n");
            opcao=0;
        }
    }while(opcao>=0 && opcao<6);
}

void listarDados()
{
    int i, menuVoltar;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        if(Cadastro[i].nome_paciente != NULL)
        {
            printf("\n\nNome do paciente:", Cadastro[i].nome_paciente);
            printf("\nCPF do paciente:", Cadastro[i].cpf_paciente);
            printf("\nNumero da carteirinha:", Cadastro[i].numero_carteirinha);
            printf("\nNome do medico: ", Cadastro[i].nome_medico);
            printf("\nEspecialidade do medico: ", Cadastro[i].especialidade_medico);
            printf("\nData da consulta: ", Cadastro[i].data_consulta);
            printf("\nData da revisao: ", Cadastro[i].data_revisao);
            printf("\nCodigo do medicamento: ", Cadastro[i].codigo_medicamento);
            printf("\nCodigo do fornecedor: ", Cadastro[i].codigo_fornecedor);
            printf("\nValor do medicamento: ", Cadastro[i].valor_medicamento);
        }
    }
    printf("Pressione 0 para volta ao menu principal");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &menuVoltar);
    if(menuVoltar == 0)
    {
        opcao = 0;
    }
    system("cls");
}

void cadastrar(int cod, int pos)
{
    int i;

    do{
        pos = verifica_pos();
        Cadastro[pos]. = cod;

        printf("\nDigite o Nome do paciente: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].nome_paciente);
        printf("\nDigite o CPF do paciente: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].cpf_paciente);
        printf("\nDigite o numero da carteirinha do paciente: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].numero_carteirinha);
        printf("\nDigite o nome do medico: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].nome_medico);
        printf("\nDigite a especialidade do medico: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].especialidade_medico);
        printf("\nDigite a data da consulta: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].data_consulta);
        printf("\nDigite a data da revisão: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].data_revisao);
        printf("\nDigite o codigo do medicamento: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].codigo_medicamento);
        printf("\nDigite o codigo do fornecedor: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].codigo_fornecedor);
        printf("\nDigite o valor do medicamento: ");
        gets(Cadastro[pos].valor_medicamento);

        Cadastro[pos].vazio = 1;
        opt ==1;
        getchar();
    }while(opt==1);

    system("cls");
    main();
}

void pesquisar(void)
{
    int cont = 0, cod;
    printf("\nEntre com o código\n");
    scanf("%d",&cod);
    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");
    while (cont <= SIZE)
    {
        if (Cadastro[cont].cod == cod)
        {
            if (Cadastro[cont].vazio == 1)
            {
                printf("\n\nNome do paciente:", Cadastro[cont].nome_paciente);
                printf("\nCPF do paciente:", Cadastro[cont].cpf_paciente);
                printf("\nNumero da carteirinha:", Cadastro[cont].numero_carteirinha);
                printf("\nNome do medico: ", Cadastro[cont].nome_medico);
                printf("\nEspecialidade do medico: ", Cadastro[cont].especialidade_medico);
                printf("\nData da consulta: ", Cadastro[cont].data_consulta);
                printf("\nData da revisao: ", Cadastro[cont].data_revisao);
                printf("\nCodigo do medicamento: ", Cadastro[cont].codigo_medicamento);
                printf("\nCodigo do fornecedor: ", Cadastro[cont].codigo_fornecedor);
                printf("\nValor do medicamento: ", Cadastro[cont].valor_medicamento);
            }
            system ("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
    }
    cont++;
    if (cont > 200)
    {
    printf("\nCódigo não encontrado, pressione enter para volar ao menu principal\n");
    getchar();
    system("cls");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may want to look into writing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve the quality of your question (and the answers you'll get :-) ).

Comment: Don't use `typedef`. It will make it harder for you to understand concepts well.

Comment: Ignoring the incorrect array name `Cadastro[pos]. = cod;` seems to be missing a variable name.

Comment: In my experience with both gcc and clang, the first error is one that you want to look at.  The other errors may be spurious because the parser lost track.  As another person commented, the line with `Cadastro[pos]. = cod;` is missing a variable name after the '.'.  Perhaps you meant to have it read `Cadastro[pos].cod = cod;` instead?

Answer (score 1):

`Cadastro` is the name of the type. You'll want to use `cadastro`, the name of the variable. E.g.:

```
printf("\n\nNome do paciente:", cadastro[i].nome_paciente);
```